# Won't recall variable from within boolean expression

Tags: java, boolean

I'm having trouble finding what exactly java is having trouble with when recalling a variable. I'm creating a simple chatbot and this is what I have so far:

```
public class Chatbot {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hi! How are you? My name is Chatbot! What is yours? ");
        if (name.compareTo("a")<0){
            String city = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nice to meet you! Where are you from, "+name);
        }
        else
        {
            String city = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Huh. That's a strange name. Where are you from,"+name);  
        }


        if (!city.equals("Seattle")){

        }

    }
}
```

My problem is that java won't recognize the variable city within the if else statements and so says city is not resolved. How do I get java to recognize the objects within a boolean expression? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Declare city before condition.

Comment: The variable `city` is local only to the if-else block.

Comment: http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html  Scroll down to "Loop Scope"

Comment: Read up on [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29), as Java uses block scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently `city`'s scope is only confined to if or else block.Increase its scope by making it a local variable by declaring it at method level.

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hi! How are you? My name is Chatbot! What is yours? ");
String city="";
if (name.compareTo("a")<0){
    city = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nice to meet you! Where are you from, "+name);
}
else
    {
    city = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Huh. That's a strange name. Where are you from,"+name);  
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Decalre  `String city = null`  on top. then use it.It must be out of `if  else` block.

```
String city=null;
    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hi! How are you? My name is Chatbot! What is yours? ");
if (name.compareTo("a")<0){
            city = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nice to meet you! Where are you from, "+name);
        }
        else
        {
            city = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Huh. That's a strange name. Where are you from,"+name);  
        }
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be global, just a little less local than they (there are actually two different variables called city, one in the `if`and one in the `else`) currently is.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, you need to declare city outside the if-else block, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hi! How are you? My name is Chatbot! What is yours?");
    String city = null;
    if (name.compareTo("a")<0){
       city = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nice to meet you! Where are you from, "+name);
    }
        else
    {
        city = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Huh. That's a strange name. Where are you from,"+name);  
    }
    if (!city.equals("Seattle")){

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try following hope it helps.

```
 public static void main( String[] args )
        {

            String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Hi! How are you? My name is Chatbot! What is yours? " );
            String city = "";
            if ( name.compareTo( "a" ) < 0 )
            {

                city = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Nice to meet you! Where are you from, " + name );
            }
            else
            {
                city = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Huh. That's a strange name. Where are you from," + name );
            }

            if ( !city.equals( "Seattle" ) )
            {

            }

        }
```